# Are there any performance gains when creating new variable passed by reference vs. passed by value?

Tags: performance, variables, reference

I'm not interested in concrete values, but just theoretical answers.

1. For example, in loops when we need
   to use the same values over and
   over, would it work faster if values
   would be passed by reference instead
   of value?
2. And what about objects? Assuming
   that our object contains some values
   for this specific instance of an
   object. Instead of instantiating new
   object, can we pass it by reference
   to gain performance wise? Or should
   we `clone` it?

I hope I've made myself clear, thanks in advance.

Comment: To a *certain* extent, it depends on the language. (Or at least the specifics of a good answer will.) Are you referring to PHP?

Comment: @middaparka, I'm referring to PHP, but will be glad for answers related to other languages.

Comment: PHP is different from other languages. When passing *by value*, many languages copy value and then pass this copy. PHP creates new "reference" to a value instead and copies value only when it is being changed. E.g., if you create 1MB string and set it as value of 3 variables (`$str = '...'; $str2 = $str; $str3 = $str;`), you get only *one* value with 1MB size and 3 variables that point to the same value. When you modify a value (e.g., `$str3`), value is being copied and edited and it gets assigned to `$str3`, so you now have 1 variable pointing to new 1MB value, 2 variables - to the old value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you are interested in is performance, then as a general rule, pass by reference performs better than pass by value.

Comment: The most basic is that if I PBV you an object, any changes you make in the function are local to your copy of the object - if you want to write a function which looks up your zip+4 code and sets it on the object, you'd have to PBR.  And you have to worry about const correctness more, for the same reason (you don't want some subfunction to wind up clobbering your object).

Comment: *This tends to be especially true for objects.* <-- how comes? In some languages, objects are essentially pointers.

Comment: @binaryLV, My guess would be that passing objects by reference `!=` instantiating a new object. The latter creates a new memory chunk, where reference reads from previously set memory chunk. _kinda weird explanation, excuse me, but I hope you get my point.._

Comment: Tom, simple test - create an object, pass it "by value" to a function which changes some value in passed object, then check that value outside the function. Is it changed? In PHP - yes. That means that although object was passed to a function "by value", it was still a reference to the same object, to the same space in memory. As far as I remember, it was the same in Delphi, and `sizeof(object)` was the same as `sizeof(pointer)`. C++ is different though, at least when variable is defined as an object which is created automatically (i.e., `MyClass obj` rather than `MyClass *obj`).

Comment: The "tends to be" (as opposed to "is") was designed to bypass exactly this kind of detail, but I'm happy to see it come up in the comments.  (It seemed to me that the OP was asking a very general question, so I thought a very general answer was appropriate.)

Comment: "*Tends to be especially true for objects*" does not seem to be a *general* statement. PHP (as OP stated in comments, he's mostly interested in PHP), JavaScript, Delphi - they all pass objects "by reference" by default. I believe Java and .NET languages do the same, though I cannot test it right now.

Comment: If talking about passing small values like integers, I've seen a case where passing by reference is slower. I'm not sure why. Maybe compiler may guess that some value is small enough for keeping it in CPU register (rather than RAM)? If passing by value, this might be possible. If passing by reference - impossible.

Comment: I've edited out the sentence that triggered this discussion.  The sentence did not add any substantial information or value to the answer anyway.  (The discussion, though, contains useful info and I hope people will leave it here for interested parties.)

Answer (score 3):

The general rule on modern CPUs is "math is fast, memory is slow".

If you are talking about C++, passing integers, floats, and even small objects by *value* is likely to be faster.  Pass-by-reference can prevent a variety of compiler optimizations thanks to aliasing concerns.

For larger objects, passing by reference will be faster.  (Definitely do not clone them, because memory is slow.)

The real answer to this question, though, is to write your code in a natural, straightforward way, and do not worry about this sort of question until your profiler tells you to.

[update, to elaborate on the aliasing problem]

For example, consider the following two functions:

```
void
foo1(int a, int b, int &c, int &d)
{
    c = a + b;
    d = a - b;
}

void
foo2(const int &a, const int &b, int &c, int &d)
{
    c = a + b;
    d = a - b;
}
```

With optimization enabled, my compiler (gcc 4.5.2, x86_64) produces this code for foo1:

```
leal    (%rsi,%rdi), %eax
subl    %esi, %edi
movl    %eax, (%rdx)
movl    %edi, (%rcx)
ret
```

...and this for foo2:

```
movl    (%rsi), %eax
addl    (%rdi), %eax
movl    %eax, (%rdx)
movl    (%rdi), %eax
subl    (%rsi), %eax
movl    %eax, (%rcx)
ret
```

Your compiler will do something similar.  The problem is that in foo2, "c" or "d" might refer to the same memory location as "a" or "b", so the compiler has to insert extra loads/stores to worry about that case.

This is a trivial example, but more complex ones show similar behavior.  For simple types and even small structs, pass by value usually results in faster code.

Comment: In C++, usually pass-by-const-reference unless the only thing the function would do with the reference is make a copy.  In which case, pass by value, giving the compiler a better chance to optimize away the copy.

Comment: @Ben: That is simply not true.  The problem with references is that they can _alias_, which makes it harder for the compiler to lift sub-expressions into registers, hoist them out of loops, etc.

Comment: Those two functions don't have the same behavior.  If `d` is supposed to be calculated based on the values of `a` and `b` on entry to the function, you'd need to copy them... in which case my rule says pass-by-value and let the compiler perform the copy.  Also note that an assembly listing doesn't give much information about performance.  Memory is slow only when it's a cache miss.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely. Pass-by-reference is virtually always a big win, *especially* for class types where a nontrivial constructor and destructor must run. The only times where you could expect pass-by-value to win might be for passing data smaller than a pointer -- individual characters, for example -- and even then, it'd be a very hardware-specific argument.

Answer (score 1):

Pass by value copies the value - if it's a small primitive - say, int, it's not much going to matter - you either copy the int on to the stack to make the call, or you copy its address (same size, roughly, so no real gain).

For a large non-trivial object, pass by value will be much more costly - you build a new copy of that object.

It's unclear what you mean about the loop - PBV/PBR will mainly only matter during function calls.

Comment: About the loop I meant running a function inside loop which works with these values (PBV/PBR).

Comment: @Tom in that case, you'd definitely want to pass by reference if your object is at all non-trivial, otherwise each invocation would cause you to construct a new copy of the object.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the language and the implementation. Generally, passing by reference is faster because all you have to pass is an address (a pointer). For data types smaller than a pointer, there *may* be a small savings in memory and/or time to pass the value. However, in most language copying even a small object would require the call to a copy constructor of some kind, which would kill any possible savings. On the other hand, passing by reference creates an object or variable alias, which in some languages can be a problem. Also, in some languages you can't pass a compile-time constant by reference; the compiler turns a call `func(1)` into something like `int _1 = 1; func(_1)`.

I should also mention that in some languages (like Java) it is impossible to pass an object by value or a primitive type by reference. For those languages, of course, your question is moot.